# Difference between protected[package] and private[package] for a singleton object

Tags: scala, object, inheritance, scope

I am trying to restrict access to methods present in an object to the package the object belongs to.
The method is used by many classes inside the package. I have two options:

```
protected[pkg] object MyObject{....}
```

or

```
private[pkg] object MyObject{....}
```

Both of them work just fine. 
My question is, since an object cannot be extended by any class/object anyway, aren't they equivalent?

Answer (score 4):

Top-level, yes, they wind up as public in Java (not default access).

But also:

```
package accesstest {
    trait T {
        protected[accesstest] object Foo { def foo = 7 }
        private[accesstest] object Bar { def bar =  8 }
    }

    object Test extends App {
        val t = new T {}
        Console println t.Foo.foo
        Console println t.Bar.bar
        Console println other.Other.foo
    }
}
package other {
    object Other extends accesstest.T {
        def foo = Foo.foo
        //def bar = Bar.bar  // nope
    }
}
```

So what counts is the extensibility and access of the enclosing thing.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Could you please elaborate a little on the explanation?

Comment: I just meant that protected vs private matters sometimes for objects. Nothing deep.  There are examples of access turning out not to be private, which were surprising, but I was too lazy to search for them

Comment: Okay. So, is this a right generalization: Fields of a protected[pkg] object can be accessed in the sub-packages while those of private[pkg] object cannot be?

Comment: Ah, I see. My bad. I thought `other` is a subpackage of `accesstest`. So, do you mean the `protected` keyword is for the structure 'enclosing' the object?